# PDI - How to monitor kettle Transformation and Jobs?

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I'm try to create web app to monitor my transformation and job. I will show all the status (begin datetime, run time duration, finish datetime, status, etc) on web app in live(my web app will refresh automatically to check the status). Is there any way to collect the log of transformation and job? My idea is to use that log for my web app. Or any other way that Could be better than mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In https://github.com/alaindebecker/ETL-pilot, you'll learn how to use how to display the status of your transformation on a web site (which may be your local host).

It has been tested in the UN, and with Cédric we have found a way to do it at job level and how to implement a button to restart a transformation. We did not finish (and publish) this work not because we were lazy, and because there were no demand for it.

If you want to talk about you need, drop a issue in the git.

Comment: how about the error? pentaho logging only show number of error but not the detail of error. how to show or see the detail of error?

Comment: Drop issues and feedback on the git. Your opinion matters!